# using freemarker and spring to construct templates

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I am new to freemarker.  I have a spring application that I am planning to use with freemarker.  Templates will be stored in database and based on the login, I want to retrieve the template from database.  Can any one tell me how to configure the freemarker in spring and get the html tags as a string after constructing the template.  I did googling but I could not understand much.

I tried till this level. In spring I have done till this level. Finally I want html tags in a string.

```
// Spring freemarker specific code
Configuration configuration = freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration();
StringTemplateLoader stringTemplateLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
// My application specific code
String temp = tempLoader.getTemplateForCurrentLogin();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tie together the bits of code you posted, you can do something like this:

```
// you already have this bit
String templateText = tempLoader.getTemplateForCurrentLogin();

// now programmatically instantiate a template
Template t = new Template("t", new StringReader(templateText), new Configuration());

// now use the Spring utility class to process it into a string
// myData is your data model
String output = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, myData);
```

Answer (score 1):

This java method will process the freemarker template and will give html tags as String after constructing the template.

```
public static String  processFreemarkerTemplate(String fileName) {

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_24);

        try {
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("path/of/freemarker/template"));
            cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
            cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);

            Template template = cfg.getTemplate(fileName);
            template.process(objectMap, stringWriter);

        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stringWriter != null) {
                try {
                    stringWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```